# Из HTML файла взять переменные одного типа в качестве массива в C#

Tags: c#, html

(C#) У меня есть некий файл, код которого по синтаксису сильно схож с HTML. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы программа считала все значения между полями .

```
<dict>
            <key>FRAME_ID</key>
            <string>3aceeda1-482d-48ea-87fd-89a5a9e5ef1e</string>
            <key>UID</key>
            <string>3aceeda1-482d-48ea-87fd-89a5a9e5ef1e</string>
            <key>FRAME_TYPE</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>DURATION</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>IS_FRAME_PAUSED_FOR_AUDIO</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>FRAME_ID</key>
            <string>01bee6f7-1ff1-43cc-a804-eab0d2c8a2b3</string>
            <key>UID</key>
            <string>01bee6f7-1ff1-43cc-a804-eab0d2c8a2b3</string>
            <key>FRAME_TYPE</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>DURATION</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>IS_FRAME_PAUSED_FOR_AUDIO</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>FRAME_ID</key>
            <string>fd11ffe2-23c4-4325-9b35-24d2d9ab7193</string>
            <key>UID</key>
            <string>fd11ffe2-23c4-4325-9b35-24d2d9ab7193</string>
            <key>FRAME_TYPE</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>DURATION</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>IS_FRAME_PAUSED_FOR_AUDIO</key>
            <false/>
```

Как это можно реализовать в C#

Answer (score 1):

С этими данными можно работать как с XML (да и по сути это он и есть), но увы, он у вас не полный и тут либо вы так скопировали, либо он у вас "битый".

- У вас есть 3 объекта `dict`, каждый такой объект должен быть закрыт в конце (`</dict>`).
  Ваш XML не содержит в конце последнего элемента закрывающий тег.
- XML не позволяет хранить в себе два и более объекта верхнего уровня, а это значит, что у вас должен быть еще какой либо объект, который будет уже внутри себя содержать все `dict`.

Если подправить то, что вы предоставили, то "валидный" XML будет следующий:

```
<SomeItems>
  <dict>
    <key>FRAME_ID</key>
    <string>3aceeda1-482d-48ea-87fd-89a5a9e5ef1e</string>
    <key>UID</key>
    <string>3aceeda1-482d-48ea-87fd-89a5a9e5ef1e</string>
    <key>FRAME_TYPE</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>DURATION</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>IS_FRAME_PAUSED_FOR_AUDIO</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>FRAME_ID</key>
    <string>01bee6f7-1ff1-43cc-a804-eab0d2c8a2b3</string>
    <key>UID</key>
    <string>01bee6f7-1ff1-43cc-a804-eab0d2c8a2b3</string>
    <key>FRAME_TYPE</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>DURATION</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>IS_FRAME_PAUSED_FOR_AUDIO</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>FRAME_ID</key>
    <string>fd11ffe2-23c4-4325-9b35-24d2d9ab7193</string>
    <key>UID</key>
    <string>fd11ffe2-23c4-4325-9b35-24d2d9ab7193</string>
    <key>FRAME_TYPE</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>DURATION</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>IS_FRAME_PAUSED_FOR_AUDIO</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</SomeItems>
```

---

С этим думаю разобрались.
Теперь давайте попробуем разобрать эти данные. Что мы видим тут?

1. Есть строгая последовательность, где сначала идет ключ, а затем идет его значение.
2. Значение в имени содержит свой тип.

Для начала разберемся с типом:

Тут отлично бы подошел подход вида

```
var value = Convert.ChangeType(объект, Type.GetType(его тип)))
```

Но увы, в c# нет например `integer` типа, есть `Int32` и тут нам придется городить свои велосипеды, например, такие:

```
private static object CastTo(string value, string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "integer":
            if (int.TryParse(value, out int intRes)) return intRes;
            break;
        default:
            if (bool.TryParse(type, out bool boolRes)) return boolRes;
            break;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Пояснение:

- На вход передается методу значение и его тип.
- Если тип подходит одному из условий, то мы попытаемся конвертировать значение в него и при удаче вернуть `object`.
- Если тип непонятен (у вас это `<false/>`), то пытаемся конвертировать в `bool`.
- Если все наши попытки преобразовать провалились, то возвращаем `string` результат.

Ну теперь давайте разберем XML:

```
var document = XElement.Load("Test.xml");
var items = document.Descendants("dict");

var result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < item.Elements().Count(); i += 2)
    {
        var key = item.Elements().ElementAt(i).Value;
        var valueElement = item.Elements().ElementAt(i + 1);

        var value = CastTo(valueElement.Value, valueElement.Name.LocalName);

        dict.Add(key, value);
    }

    result.Add(dict);
}
```

Поясняю:

- `XElement.Load("Test.xml");` - загружаем файл.
- `document.Descendants("dict");` - берем из файла все `dict` объекты.
- `foreach (var item in items)` - проходимся по ним и делаем с каждым объектом:

  - `for (int i = 0; i < item.Elements().Count(); i += 2)` - делаем цикл, который будет с шагом по 2, давать нам индекс до тех пор, пока кол-во элементов внутри одного `dict` будет больше, чем индекс (будем получать int значения `0 2 4 6...`).
  - `item.Elements().ElementAt(i).Value;` - берем значение из строк вида `<key>`.
  - `item.Elements().ElementAt(i + 1);` - берем следующий после `<key>` объект.
  - `CastTo(valueElement.Value, valueElement.Name.LocalName);` - вызываем ранее созданный метод, который вернет нам сконвертированное значение. На вход отдаем значение внутри скобок и название (`integer` и др).
  - `dict.Add(key, value);` - добавляем результат во временный словарь.
- `result.Add(dict);` - добавляем временный словарь в основной "список словарей".

Собственно все, результатом будет нечто такое:

[image: Result]

Как видим, все данные успешно загрузились и имеют соответствующий тип.
Теперь мы можем например сделать так:

```
var someValue = (bool)result[0]["IS_FRAME_PAUSED_FOR_AUDIO"];
```